# How to split json response string based on the whitespace between them in android

Tags: android, string, split, jsonresponse

I have a json response string like this: 2015-09-30 11:09:00 (date and time is a single string)
I need to add "at" between "2015-09-30" and "11:09:00". How can I split this date and time so that I can add the word "at" in between them. 
 My requirement::I displayed the date and time in a single textview(without splitting them). But now when I split this, how can I display them on two different text view,i.e; date in first textview and time in second text view.Please help me to sort this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String jsonString = "2015-09-30 11:09:00";
String dateTime[]=jsonString.split(" ");
String finalStr = dateTime[1]+" at "+dateTime[0];
```

i guess this should work

or `String finalStr = jsonString.replace(" "," at ");`

Comment: this jsonString value always varies, so I can't assign it as a single value like this :jsonString = "2015-09-30 11:09:00". How can I split the date and time for all json response values?

Answer (score 0):

Use `replaceFirst`

```
string.replaceFirst("[ \\t]+", " at ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split() for that :

```
String[] dateTimeArray = dateTimeString.split(" ");
String date = dateTimeArray[0]; // date
String time = dateTimeArray[1]; // time
```

**Edit**

set it to two different textviews:

```
tvFirstTextView.setText(date);
tvSecondTextView.setText("at " +time);
```

Comment: @Sindhu check my edited answer and accept as correct if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] DateTime = ANY_JSON_STRING.split(" ");
String Date = DateTime[0];
String Time = DateTime[1];
```

Now you can play with String as per your requirement i.e. Date + " at " + Times, or anything else like that.